# Pass the value of input hidden an add cart to checkout/cart

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, checkout, onepage-checkout

I have a question, i have physical stores with a shop code.
When a customer selects from the list a particular store (with fancybox):
[image]

I inform under the button add to the basket an input hidden with the code of the store in question in javascript.

[image]

How can I add code to the product selected by the customer when he clicks add to cart and find this information in the checkout / cart page?

Can you help or explain me ?

Comment: you can use custom option & set custom option value by jquery and make it hide by css so it will get you cart & checkout also in order view admin panel

Comment: No i do not think that using the options in my case is necessary.
I know that with the customer's session we can see the products he has added. In this case is it possible to add the value of my variable in the customer's session with the product id? If possible how i can do this ?